# Duplicate Worksheet but keep values only in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-gsuite

I have a google sheets doc linked to another sheets document via IMPORTRANGE.

I wish to have a duplicate which mantains Values only without the link data, since i am lookin to update the data and make like monthly reports based on that.

Is there a way to duplicate the sheets via script or another function or either break the links but mantain the values?

Answer (score 0):

Make the copy and enable the IMPORTRANGE(s).

Then select the entire sheet by clicking the blank rectangle just above the left-hand row numbers and to the left of the top column letters. With the sheet selected, click Ctrl-C to copy to clipboard.

With the full-sheet selection still active, hit Ctrl-V for "Paste Special." Look for a clipboard icon to appear lower-right on the visible screen area. Click it and choose "Paste values only."

Comment: Yes it should work, but having 30+ Tabs makes this not optimal, mostly for a report destined to be done montlhy}